# asp.net parameter is not valid when using bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void LoadButtonImage()
{
    if(buttonPicture != null)
        buttonPicture.Dispose();

    string templateFileName = "PicTemplate/RoundedRectangle.png";
    buttonPicture = new Bitmap(templateFileName);
}
```

This is my coding ..... parameter is not valid in runtime ... what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you're pointing to the wrong location. Try switching it to

```
new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(templateFileName)).
```